# Create Product Permutation of irregularly Nested Loop

Tags: python, list, nested, permutation

Apologies for the lengthy Explanation, I have two nested lists, one with reference values for a series of fields, called `dl`, and another with field names, called `k_all_tbl`. They look like the bellow:

```
dl = [[['Aegon', 'Aviva', 'HSBC', 'Zurich'], 'S_Field_1_0'],
            [['Level Life Cover', 'Family Income Benefit', 'Whole of Life Cover'],
            'Field_1 policy type'],
            [['Sum assured', 'Benefit amount'], 'Field_2'],
            [['£ii_Field_52_1', '£ii_Field_53_2 a month'], 'Field_3'],
            [['ii_Field_62_1 years', 'to age ii_Field_63_2', 'Whole of life'], 'Field_4'],
             .....]
```

The `dl` list has unknown length `n`, but each element `dl[i]` has 2 lists nested within, the first (`dl[i][0]`) being possible replacements for the second element (`dl[i][1]`).

`k_all_tbl` looks like this :

```
k_all_tbl =[[[[['Name']], [['INSERT_3']]],
            [[['Product']], [['S_Field_1_0'], [' '], ['Field_1 policy type']]],
            [[['Field_2']], [['Field_3']]],

           [[[['Name']], [['INSERT_9']]],
            [[['Product']],
             [['INSERT_10'], [' '], ['S_Field_19_18'], [' '], ['INSERT_11']]],
            [[['Sum assured']], [['£'], ['INSERT_12']]],
             .....]
```

k_all_tbl (extracted from a table data) also has unknown length `m`, but each element `k_all_tbll[j]` (each row)  has 2 lists nested within, with (`k_all_tbll[j][0]`) and  (`k_all_tbll[j][1]`) (column1 and column2 of original table) being linked.

The short version of the requirement is that I need to create the following output:

```
k_all_tbl[0] =[[['Name'], ['INSERT_3']],
                [[['Product']], [['Aegon', ' ', 'Level Life Cover'],
                  ['Aegon', ' ', 'Family Income Benefit'],
                  ['Aegon', ' ', 'Whole of Life Cover'],
                  ['Aviva', ' ', 'Level Life Cover'],
                  ['Aviva', ' ', 'Family Income Benefit'],
                  ['Aviva', ' ', 'Whole of Life Cover'],
                  ['HSBC', ' ', 'Level Life Cover'],
                  ['HSBC', ' ', 'Family Income Benefit'],
                  ['HSBC', ' ', 'Whole of Life Cover'],
                  ['Zurich', ' ', 'Level Life Cover'],
                  ['Zurich', ' ', 'Family Income Benefit'],
                  ['Zurich', ' ', 'Whole of Life Cover']]],

                [[['Sum assured', '£ii_Field_52_1'],
                  ['Sum assured', '£ii_Field_53_2 a month'],
                  ['Benefit amount', '£ii_Field_52_1'],
                  ['Benefit amount', '£ii_Field_53_2 a month']]]
```

### However the code Ive shared bellow in detail and steps does not get me here, it crashes without executing, or gives me the wrong permutation. Any and all help would be appreciated. Details explanation and code tried bellow.

Method Tried:

I try to first: for each element in `k_all_tbl[j][0][k]` that corresponds to an element `dl[i][1]`, to replace `k_all_tbl[j][0][k]` with (`dl[i][0]`). Exmaple of output is:

```
k_all_tbl[0] =[[[[['Name']], [['INSERT_3']]],
            [[['Product']], [[['Aegon', 'Aviva', 'HSBC', 'Zurich']], [' '], [['Level Life Cover', 'Family Income Benefit', 'Whole of Life Cover']]]],
            [[[['Sum assured', 'Benefit amount']]], [[['£ii_Field_52_1', '£ii_Field_53_2 a month']]]]
```

I have achieved the above by running the following code:

```
for ik in range(0,len(k_all_tbl)):
    k_all_tbl[ik] = unlevel(k_all_tbl[ik])
    for ikk in range(0,len(k_all_tbl[ik])):

            for ikkk in range(0,(len (k_all_tbl[ik][ikk]))):

                    for res1 in dropdown_result:
                        if isinstance(k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk], list)==False: 

                            if  k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk] == res1[1]:
                                k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk] = res1[0]


                        if len(k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk]) >1:
                            for ikkkk in range(0,(len (k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk]))):
                                if  k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk][ikkkk] == res1[1]:
                                    k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk][ikkkk] = res1 [0]
```

where the function `unlevel` is used to access items inside single element nested lists, i.e. `unlevel([[[[["target"]],1]]]) = '[[target],1]'` , and is defined as:

```
def unlevel(obj):
    while isinstance(obj, list) and len(obj) == 1:
        obj = obj[0]
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [unlevel(item) for item in obj]
    else:
        return obj
```

I then need to remove unecessary brackets, and create the "product" of each of the elements in `k_all_tbl` for example for `k_all_tbl[0]`:

```
k_all_tbl[0] =[[['Name'], ['INSERT_3']],
                [[['Product']], [['Aegon', ' ', 'Level Life Cover'],
                  ['Aegon', ' ', 'Family Income Benefit'],
                  ['Aegon', ' ', 'Whole of Life Cover'],
                  ['Aviva', ' ', 'Level Life Cover'],
                  ['Aviva', ' ', 'Family Income Benefit'],
                  ['Aviva', ' ', 'Whole of Life Cover'],
                  ['HSBC', ' ', 'Level Life Cover'],
                  ['HSBC', ' ', 'Family Income Benefit'],
                  ['HSBC', ' ', 'Whole of Life Cover'],
                  ['Zurich', ' ', 'Level Life Cover'],
                  ['Zurich', ' ', 'Family Income Benefit'],
                  ['Zurich', ' ', 'Whole of Life Cover']]],

                [[['Sum assured', '£ii_Field_52_1'],
                  ['Sum assured', '£ii_Field_53_2 a month'],
                  ['Benefit amount', '£ii_Field_52_1'],
                  ['Benefit amount', '£ii_Field_53_2 a month']]]
```

Ive tried the following two functions to bottom of the code above to try to achieve this:

```
for ik in range(0,len(k_all_tbl)):
        #loop through lists inside nested list -if single element list is nested, remove list before comparison, if more than 1 element keep list, and iterativley compare
        for ikk in range(0,len(k_all_tbl[ik])):

            for ikkk in range(0,(len (k_all_tbl[ik][ikk]))):

                    for res1 in dl:
                        if isinstance(k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk],list)==True and len(k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk])==1:
                            k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk] = unlevel(k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk])
                            if  k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk] == res1[1]:
                                k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk] = res1[0]
                             k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk] = unlistme(k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk])
                             k_all_tbl[ik][ikk] = spreadm(k_all_tbl[ik][ikk])


                        if len(k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk]) >1:
                            for ikkkk in range(0,(len (k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk]))):
                                if  k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk][ikkkk] == res1[1]:
                                    k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk][ikkkk] = res1 [0]
                            k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk] = unlistme(k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk])
                            k_all_tbl[ik][ikk] = spreadm(k_all_tbl[ik][ikk])
##function to create permutations
def product(llist):
    result = [[]]
    for lst in llist:
        result = [x + [y] for x in result for y in lst]
    return result


#Function to put single string elements in lists, i.e. "Target" must be changed to ["Target"], otherise the loop will iterate accross "T"-"A"-"R"-"G"-"E"-"T" characters:
def unlistme(ktest):
        ktest2 = []
        for ktt in ktest:
            kttls=[]
            if isinstance(ktt,list)==True:
                ktest2.append(ktt)
            if isinstance(ktt,list)==False:
                kttls.append(ktt)
                ktest2.append(kttls)
        return(ktest2)


#function to open nested list into sublist using product
def spreadm(kx2):
    if isinstance(kx2,list) ==True:
    
        out = product(kx2)
    else:
            out = kx2
    return(out)
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks very much will read the documentation, I am maybe hoping there is a less loopy, messy way of manually doing this, a function I might have missed or mapping in itertools...

Comment: From a cursory glance, you may benefit from learning `pandas`. This is a Python library that is commonly used for storing and manipulating tables of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to solve this, I used the following two loops, with the functions the same as defined above in OP. The first loop does the replacement with corresponding fields in the reference dataframe dl, while the second loop searches through the third level nests, and if at least one list exists, attempts to create permutations:

```
for ik in range(0,len(k_all_tbl)):
    k_all_tbl[ik] = unlevel(k_all_tbl[ik])
    for ikk in range(0,len(k_all_tbl[ik])):

            for ikkk in range(0,(len (k_all_tbl[ik][ikk]))):

                    for res1 in dl:
                        if isinstance(k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk], list)==False: 

                            if  k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk] == res1[1]:
                                k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk] = res1[0]


                        if len(k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk]) >1:
                            for ikkkk in range(0,(len (k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk]))):
                                if  k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk][ikkkk] == res1[1]:
                                    k_all_tbl[ik][ikk][ikkk][ikkkk] = res1 [0]



for kj in range(0,len(k_all_tbl)):
    for kj1 in range(0,len(k_all_tbl[kj])):
        for kz in range(0,len(k_all_tbl[kj][kj1])):
            
            if any(isinstance(i, list) for i in k_all_tbl[kj][kj1][kz])==True: #and any(isinstance(i, str) for i in k_all_tbl[kj][kj1])==True:
                k_all_tbl[kj][kj1][kz] = spreadm(unlistme(k_all_tbl[kj][kj1][kz]))
```

output:

```
[[['Name', 'INSERT_3'],
  ['Product',
   [['Aegon', ' ', 'Level Life Cover'],
    ['Aegon', ' ', 'Family Income Benefit'],
    ['Aegon', ' ', 'Whole of Life Cover'],
    ['Aviva', ' ', 'Level Life Cover'],
    ['Aviva', ' ', 'Family Income Benefit'],
    ['Aviva', ' ', 'Whole of Life Cover'],
    ['HSBC', ' ', 'Level Life Cover'],
    ['HSBC', ' ', 'Family Income Benefit'],
    ['HSBC', ' ', 'Whole of Life Cover'],
    ['Zurich', ' ', 'Level Life Cover'],
    ['Zurich', ' ', 'Family Income Benefit'],
    ['Zurich', ' ', 'Whole of Life Cover']]],
  [['Sum assured', 'Benefit amount'],
   ['£ii_Field_52_1', '£ii_Field_53_2 a month']],
  ['Term', ['ii_Field_62_1 years', 'to age ii_Field_63_2', 'Whole of life']],
  ['Premium', ['£', 'INSERT_4', ' a month']],
  ['Payable on', ['Death', 'First death']],
  ['Trust recommended', ['Yes', 'No']]],
 [['Name', 'INSERT_9'],
   .....]
```